# Can pyspark implement custom serialized objects

Tags: pyspark, serializable

I plan to use kafaka to send data in pyspark. I find out through searching materials that I need to make a customized serialization of producer so that I can broadcast the object. But how can I realize this function in pyspark?

spark==2.2.1

This is how it is implemented in scala:

```scala
public class KafkaProducer implements Serializable {

  public static final String METADATA_BROKER_LIST_KEY = "metadata.broker.list";
  public static final String SERIALIZER_CLASS_KEY = "serializer.class";
  public static final String SERIALIZER_CLASS_VALUE = "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder";

  private static KafkaProducer instance = null;

  private Producer producer;

  private KafkaProducer(String brokerList) {

    Preconditions.checkArgument(StringUtils.isNotBlank(brokerList), "kafka brokerList is blank...");

    // set properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(METADATA_BROKER_LIST_KEY, brokerList);
    properties.put(SERIALIZER_CLASS_KEY, SERIALIZER_CLASS_VALUE);
    properties.put("kafka.message.CompressionCodec", "1");
    properties.put("client.id", "streaming-kafka-output");
    ProducerConfig producerConfig = new ProducerConfig(properties);
    this.producer = new Producer(producerConfig);
  }

  public static synchronized KafkaProducer getInstance(String brokerList) {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new KafkaProducer(brokerList);
      System.out.println("初始化 kafka producer...");
    }
    return instance;
  }

  // 单条发送
  public void send(KeyedMessage<String, String> keyedMessage) {
    producer.send(keyedMessage);
  }

  // 批量发送
  public void send(List<KeyedMessage<String, String>> keyedMessageList) {
    producer.send(keyedMessageList);
  }

  public void shutdown() {
    producer.close();
  }


}
```

How does this work in pysaprk?

Answer (score 0):

hope below example helps you:

from pyspark.context import SparkContext

from pyspark.serializers import MarshalSerializer

sc = SparkContext("local", "serialization app", serializer = MarshalSerializer())

print(sc.parallelize(list(range(1000))).map(lambda x: 2 * x).take(10))

sc.stop()

Note: you can use PickleSerializer or MarshalSerializer

MarshalSerializer is faster than PickleSerializer but supports fewer datatypes.